# Setting Environment When Publishing An MVC 6 Web App

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm testing out development in Dot Net Core, and I'm up to deploying my application. For now I've done a simple file publish to my local PC, and then copied the files onto the remote server.

When I view the website, I can see that it is running in either the Staging or Production environment due to me being served minified files (Which are specified in the view).

However I'm struggling to find any documentation to say where or how this environment can be specified at publish time. Even if I have to edit this setting directly for now that is fine, but I can't seem to find it.

Files I've checked after publish (That also includes the source files as I'm just publishing via VS2015 at the moment over getting to know the DNU commandline).

- wwwroot/web.config
- approot/web.cmd
- approot/global.json
- approot/src/myproject/project.json
- approot/src/myproject/hosting.json
- approot/src/myproject/project.json
- approot/src/myproject/Properties/launchSettings.json

Comment: Usually, I think this setting is made on either the process' shell, or at the user or machine level. You can check for environment variables in Windows (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). It should be there. Otherwise, check the launch script which may include it as well. If you deployed on Azure, it may very well have been taken care of for you at the deployment.

Comment: Sent me on the right track. Answered below for what I did for anyone else stumbling along this question :)

Comment: MSFT docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was a bit of fun. But here's the answer for a Windows machine.

The variable is system wide environment variable, I'm not sure how that's going to fly if you had two different configurations on the same machine (e.g. We have Test1, Test2, Test3 etc for different teams all on the same machine), although I suppose if you are getting to that size, you might be using something like Chef/Puppet to store configurations.

How you can set the variable system wide.

1. Right click on "My PC", "This PC", "My Computer" or the variant that you have with whichever windows you are on. Select Properties.
2. Hit Advanced System Settings (On Win10 this is on the left hand side).
3. Click Environment Variables down the bottom of this next window.
4. Click "New..." on "System Variables". Then enter in "ASPNET_ENV" with your specified environment like so....

[image]

5. Now reset IIS and you should be good to go.

I have seen other people suggest that "Hosting:Environment" is the new variable name but this did not work for me, maybe it will work for you! I can see that within launchSettings.json it uses the hosting variable, but it didn't work for me when I put it machine wide. I suppose that's the the fun of fiddling with Release Candidates! :)

Another thing to note. When launching from Visual Studio, the environment it runs in is kept in /Properties/launchSettings.json

```
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
  }
}
```

You can edit the Hosting:Environment variable here to auto launch in a different environment.

However when you run from regular IIS, the default is always "Production" (Can't see that ever going wrong.....).

Comment: How do I do this per site in IIS, not globally?

Comment: Every solution I have seen has said "Use Docker", which really sucks for those of us that might have multiple QA "sites" on a single box because they don't do an awful lot. That's the best I can tell you unfortunately. I wrote this answer a long long time ago (Almost a year ago), so things might have changed.

Comment: Docker is not an option, I'm trying to start a discussion here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2019

Comment: Use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments