# Getting an error message "An error occurred while starting the application." after publishing an API app from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-api-apps

I have a class library project based on .NET Framework 4.6.1. And another project is .NET service again based on .NET Framework 4.6.1. When I publish my service from visual studio 2017 to an API app in Azure, I get below error screen.

Few logs found:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

**Note**: Publish is successful without any error, but the application can't start.

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Please add the logs to get more clarity.

Comment: Enable stdout logs from the web.config file via Kudu and check the logs.

Comment: Is the web.config file there?

Comment: Yeah I can see it under D:\home\site\wwwroot

Comment: Many factors can cause this error page, if possible, please share us your project, which will help us find and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493259/asp-net-core-publish-error-an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application/51988150

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment, many factors can cause this generic error page, and it is difficult to find the root cause of the issue based on generic error message `an error occurred while starting the application`. For troubleshooting, you can [use ***CaptureStartupErrors*** and the ***detailedErrors*** key to display details of startup exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting#configuring-a-host).

**Capture Startup Errors**

```
new WebHostBuilder()
.CaptureStartupErrors(true)
```

**Detailed Errors**

```
new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
```