# How to set the 'web.config' file to show the full error message (.NET Core 2.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, iis-10

I hosted my ASP.NET Core app on [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) (using the publish-in- folder method). I tried to create my own *web.config* file to see detailed error messages on the client side. So I added file *web.config*:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After I restarted IIS, nothing happened. Clients still got the default error:

[image]

Can I somehow get additional information about errors using file *web.config*?

Comment: Note that `system.web` applies to ASP.NET only, not ASP.NET Core, and `system.webServer` applies to IIS. None of them is what you should use, like the answer indicated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

web.config

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS" value="true" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380345/how-to-set-the-web-config-file-to-show-the-full-error-message-net-core-2-1/61769129#61769129) claims it doesn't work. Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56473932/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 9):

For me, enabling ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS didn't do anything, but changing ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT worked:

```xml
<environmentVariables>
  <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

More information: *[Enable the Developer Exception Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-the-developer-exception-page)*

Answer (score 7):

You can configure it in your `Startup.cs` file. By default, it shows the Developer Exception Page only in development mode:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

If you replace this part just with `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` it will always show the detailed error message.

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: yeah, I know about it. but I have specific case in which I cant change any .cs files in app. For example you can add "nativeDebugging": true in launchSettings.json and DeveloperExceptionPage will turn on automatically when you debug your app in Visual Studio. Can I somehow turn on this option use only web.config?

Comment: If you check the link, you'll see that "ASP.NET Core reads the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT at app startup" so if you `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` in command line it should work.

Answer (score 1):

**web.conf**

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DocExpressManager.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
    <environmentVariables>
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS" value="true" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue seeing the yellow screen of death, too. So, instead I sent the output of the exception to a log file by setting stdoutLogEnabled="true" and stdoutLogFile="C:\Users\SomeUser\LoggingDirectory\LogFileName". In this case, you'll get a log file named something like LogFileName_20220607193533_9648.txt.

BE SURE TO RESET IIS.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Project.Name.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\Users\SomeUser\LoggingDirectory\LogFileName" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Disclaimer: I'm not certain that you need the "customErrors mode='Off'" part but, it was there when this solution worked for me.