# an error occurred while starting the application after publishing dot net core 2 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-7.5

After publishing my .net core 2 app on IIS 7.5 I get this error:

> an error occurred while starting the application.

Is there any way to force dot net core to submit a accurate error message rather than such general message?

Comment: I think the first answer should help you here [asp-net-core-1-1-runs-fine-locally-but-when-publishing-to-azure-says-an-error-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915522/asp-net-core-1-1-runs-fine-locally-but-when-publishing-to-azure-says-an-error-o)

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493259/asp-net-core-publish-error-an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application/51988150#51988150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy the app to the shared hosting, you can not run it via console. therefore I suggest doing the following steps:

1. Open your web.config
2. Change stdoutLogEnabled=true
3. Create a logs folder(Unfortunately, the AspNetCoreModule doesn’t create the folder for you by default also If you forget to create the logs folder, an error will be logged to the Event Viewer that says: Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile \?\YourPath\logs\stdout_timestamp.log, ErrorCode = -2147024893.)
4. The “stdout” part of the value “.\logs\stdout” actually references the filename, not the folder.  Which is a bit confusing.
5. Run your request again, then open the \logs\stdout_*.log file
6. Have fun ;)

Note – you will want to turn this off after you’re done troubleshooting, as it is a performance hit.

Answer (score 31):

You can try to start your application directly on your IIS Server via the console.

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

You should get a much more verbose error there.

Comment: Note that if your application is compiled as an exe, you don't need to include `dotnet`, just execute `myapp.exe`

Comment: or simply run `myapp.exe` by double clicking the exe file. It will crash, showing startup exception on console

Answer (score 8):

I found this link helpful: [How to troubleshoot: “An error occurred...](https://scottsauber.com/2017/04/10/how-to-troubleshoot-an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application-in-asp-net-core-on-iis/). In summary:

1. In the `<aspNetCore>` element of your `web.config`, set `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true`.

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath=".\myapp.exe"
            stdoutLogEnabled="true"
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

2. Create your log folder.

   Example: Given `stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"`, create `logs\` in your application root directory. `.\logs\` is the directory where logs will be stored, and is configurable to your preference. `stdout` is a static value that'll be prepended to all file names in the log folder.
3. Run your request and open the log file.

Additional information on the ASP.NET Core module: [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Don't forget to disable logging once done!

Answer (score 4):

My problem was simply that IIS didn't had permission to write in the folder that the application files were located.

This is a very bad error to get.

Hope it will help somebody and not waste many hours on it.

Comment: pretty sure if you are running your website in the wwwroot IIS will have permissions

Answer (score 1):

I followed the following steps when I got the error in our environment after deployment.

Server: Windows Server 2016

IIS Version: 10.0

Step1: Check all configs are upto date

Step2: Verify Cors config. We have enabled cors and the list to allow is part of config.

I was able to solve with these two steps.

After deployment it will be mostly with the appsettings.config. Make sure the config is correct. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get frustrated as the error doesn't give any clue. To get the error there is a simple way

1. Open command prompt.
2. Navigate to your published folder location which is mapped to IIS.
3. Type dotnet yourapplicationddllName.dll
4. Now open http://localhost:5000 or https://localhost:5001. This will open your application.
5. Do your thing. you will get the error in the command prompt console.

This method save me several times when some critical releases gets delayed
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your Program.cs have code to get Some Folder eg : "Image Folder", etc,
you need to Create the Folder Manually in your server.

to check the error in the server folder , execute command :

```
dotnet <yourSolutionName>.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Json file, check the appsettings file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).