# how aspnet core environments are resolved when publishing?

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables

Do the aspnet core hosting environments only matter when running locally using IISExpress?

I have environment specific configuration code that switches on the environment variable. Indeed, this all works fine when I change IIS Express to match the defined environment when debugging locally.

However **when I go to publish the application, what environment will it choose? How can I control this?**

Thanks for helping clear up my confusion.

Comment: When publishing, You can set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable using command line or web.config. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor).

Comment: Thanks Sanket, that gets me most of the way there. So if I have the Staging and Production on the same server, I would have to remember to swap out this variable in the web.config prior to publishing, sound right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing in my project. I have DEV and TEST environment on same server.

Comment: Sanket, bonus question? If I DON'T specify the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the web.config, what would it choose?

Comment: By default it takes as Production