# Setting environment variables in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to setting up multiple environments in my .NET Core 2.0 application. See my code below.

#### Configuration file (Launch.JSON)

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/my.api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/my.api.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/my.api",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "requireExactSource": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

#### Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

#### StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }
    private IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
    private string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") : Configuration.GetConnectionString("Production");
        }
    }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Azuredev.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        this.HostingEnvironment = env;

        System.Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName); // Here it always give me Production.
    }
```

#### My issue

I tried to use command line like **dotnet run --environment "Development"**

So, it should run on **Development Environment**, but it always runs with **Production**, (look I have added **console.writeline** in my *startup.cs* file)

Now the strange thing is that if I use <kbd>F5</kbd> to Debug then it runs perfectly with the **development** environment.

Comment: I created a demo https://github.com/d668/NetCoreConfigTransform/ .NET Core 2.2 Console app App.config transforms using slow-cheetah

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can update your launchsettings.json to include a 'Development' profile and then run:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile "Development"
```

For further details on configuration of the launchSettings.json file see [Working with multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Note that the commandName would probably need to be "Project" (I haven't really tried this much). Example launchSettings.json as follows:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19882/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is the Profile tag comes under env tag in launch.json?

Comment: @Bharat - it is in launchSettings.json not launch.json (in the properties folder)

Comment: I believe so. I have updated my answer to include a full example launchSettings.json file. Best to refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments as the authoritative guide

Comment: it gives me error like "The specified launch profile could not be located" and productions as environement name

Comment: Where is your launchSettings.json file? It should be <web project>\properties\launchSettings.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155410/discussion-between-bharat-and-cal279).

Comment: How to debug for various environments?

Comment: @Toolkit - in Visual Studio 2017, there is a dropdown next to the green "Start debugging" button. From here you can select the "profile" that you want to run.  You could have a separate profile for "Development", "Staging" and "Production". Let me know if you want me to expand my answer a bit to illustrate this.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I have done it...

Let’s look at how I achieved this.

1. I have added all my profile settings in launchSettings.JSON
2. Program.cs remains same as I added in my question.
3. Updated startup.cs (see below)
4. CLI for run it via terminal is also different.

#### Now first let's see my project structure.

[image]

#### Code in my launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40088/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Azuredev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Azuredev"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Code in launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/my.api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/my.api.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/my.api",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "requireExactSource": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### startup.cs

```
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        this.HostingEnvironment = env;
    }
```

After this all changes, my API is working fine with both the <kbd>F5</kbd> debug option as well as CLI terminal.

To launch the application from the command line, use these keywords:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile "Development"
```

OR

```
dotnet run --launch-profile "Azuredev"
```

Comment: great what about debug? how can i set default debug for dev env variables values.?

Comment: That's magnitude more complicated than slowcheetah. I just need goddamn SMTP settings etc, why can't it be more simple

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi any solution for that mess?

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet run --environment` makes no effect on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/167).

Here's a detailed instruction on how to switch environments in a multiple ways: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

For example, you can run it from a Command line (before `dotnet run`): `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Core 3.1, it happens that you need to add:

```
.AddCommandLine(args)
```

to your ConfigurationBuilder in Program.cs

for

```
dotnet run --environment "Development"
```

to work (switch ASP.NET Core environments).

Answer (score 1):

open Powershell  , reach to the project location

First Set environment Variable using the command

**$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Qa"**

Run application from power shell
**dotnet run --no-launch-profile**