# .NET Core how to set environment variable to development

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core MVC. I ran into an error but it doesn't show the problem due the environment variable.

I can't see how to change it to developer to get my error message in the browser. Not to forget, I'm using the VS Code IDE. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As first step, please show your code.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444981/setting-environment-variables-in-net-core-2-0/46445432#46445432) and the comments below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Set` command as follow (in command prompt):

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
```

You can also use `Setx` that have permanent effect while `Set` was affecting current command window only:

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

After running `Setx`, close command window and open a new command window again.

For more info about hosting environment arguments see [here](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/). To see difference between `Set` and `Setx`, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows).

Comment: i tried but didnt work.i even get the success message of setting variable but when i run my project in integrated terminal see the Hosting environment: Production message

Comment: i guess a restart was needed for vs code to see the changes,its working now,tnx guys

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in `launchSettings.json`. Here you can set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `DEVELOPMENT`

You will find everything you need to know about working with multiple environments in .Net Core on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#startup-conventions

Comment: dont know where to put that.actually i tried some but didnt work

Comment: you should put the file in your properties