# NET MVC Toggle between Seed Data and Real Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In Net MVC Core 2, Is there a method in Visual Studio, to Toggle between artificial in-memory Seed data, and real Test Environment sql connection? We are continuously testing between two environments.

This is how to create artificial data from source: "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2, Freeman".
To Toggle between Seed Data, I have to remove all this, and then add a real connection string again in Application.json, I am trying to prevent removing/adding code. Currently beginner in MVC, only programming for few months, so trying to learn. Thank you

Create seed data

```
new Product {
Name = "Kayak", Description = "A boat for one person",
Category = "Watersports", Price = 275 },

new Product {
Name = "Lifejacket",
Description = "Protective and fashionable",
Category = "Watersports", Price = 48.95m },
```

Then in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(...
services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();

public void Configure(...
SeedData.EnsurePopulated(app);
```

Comment: Can you not read from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to automatically switch connection string, you'd need to use environment-based configurations. Then, based on your environment variable, your app would read different values.
Check this answer for more details: [Setting Environment Variables in .net Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444981/setting-environment-variables-in-net-core-2-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: can you give a code sample to modify environment variables with Seed repository? Usually stackover prefer answers to url links, thanks, I'm working to figure out how to modify code myself

Answer (score 0):

The feature, you're looking for, is in EF Core. It's .UseInMemoryDatabase option:

```
public TestDbContext Context => InMemoryContext();
    private TestDbContext InMemoryContext()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .Options;
        var context = new TestDbContext(options);

        return context;
```

}

This blog would fill the gaps: https://garywoodfine.com/entity-framework-core-memory-testing-database/

Comment: is there a  way then to switch between a real test database connection? without writing and removing code, I am looking for maybe a Visual Studio Parameter environment configuration Button, or dropdown? Thanks,

Comment: I have used those items above when writing unit tests, so familiar with it