# Is launchsettings.json in a dotnet core project used in production?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is the launchsettings.json meant to be used in production or is it only for development purposes?

The one that is created by default has ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development and also a localhost applicationUrl. Am I suppose to create separate production/staging profile or is this more of a development tool?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor

Comment: No, it's not used in production. The file itself is picked up by things like `dotnet run` and Visual Studio.

Comment: ok, so would it be correct to say that it is for development use?

Comment: Yes it would be correct.

Comment: Then why does the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app ask us to modify the `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: @variable because that is a section that starts "If the app is run locally in the Development environment". On the same page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#lsj) it states, "The launchSettings.json file: *Is only used on the local development machine *Is not deployed."

Comment: Ok I wasn't expecting something about development environment to be mentioned in the deployment documentation.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `launchSettings.json` file is only used by Visual Studio during debugging and when running the app via `dotnet run` command.

See the quote from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development-and-launchsettingsjson):

> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - contains profile settings.

So for everyone who is looking for the short confirmed answer:

**No, it's not used in production.**

Comment: Then why does the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app ask us to modify the `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: @variable it says 'If the app is run locally'

Comment: What's this instruction doing in deployment document? Does it mean run locally behind reverse proxy? Or as a developer?

Comment: @variable you asked about the same thing in the question ccomments and I have continued the discussion there.