# How does one transform SOAP EndpointAddress in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, soap

When connecting a SOAP service in .NET Core the Connected Service is shown as expected in the solution explorer

[image]

The `ConnectedService.json` does contain the definitions as supposed. I.e.

```json
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  ...
  "ExtendedData": {
    "Uri": "https://test.example.net/Service.svc",
    "Namespace": "UserWebService",
    "SelectedAccessLevelForGeneratedClass": "Public",
...
}
```

The `Uri` from `ExtendedData` ends up in the `Reference.cs` file

```c#
private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
{
    if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.WSHttpBinding_IAnvandareService))
    {
        return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://test.example.net/Service.svc");
    }
    throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
}
```

If a deployment process looks like `TEST > STAGING > PRODUCTION` one might like to have corresponding endpoints. I.e. `https://production.example.net/Service.svc`.

We use Azure Devops for build and Azure Devops/Octopus Deploy for deployments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (as I figured) was to change the endpoint address when you register the dependency i.e.

```cs
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

services.AddTransient<IAnvandareService, AnvandareServiceClient>((ctx) => new AnvandareServiceClient()
{
    Endpoint =
    {
        Address = new EndpointAddress($"https://{environment}.example.net/Service.svc")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just an expansion of the answer provided by [Eric Herlitz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417342/6901318). Primarily meant to show how to use your appsettings.json file to hold the value for the endpoint url.

You will need to add the different endpoints to your appsettings.{enviroment}.json files.

```
{
  ...
  "ServiceEndpoint": "http://someservice/service1.asmx",
   ...
}
```

Then you will need to make sure your environment variable is updated when you publish to different environments. [How to transform appsettings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432405)

In your startup class find the method ConfigureServices() and register your service for dependency injection

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ADSoap, ADSoapClient>(fac =>
        {
            var endpoint = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceEndpoint");
            return new ADSoapClient(ADSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.ADSoap12)
            {
                Endpoint =
                {
                    Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpoint))
                }
            };
        });
    }
```

Then to consume the service in some class you can inject the service into the constructor:

```
public class ADProvider : BaseProvider, IADProvider
{
    public ADSoap ADService { get; set; }

    public ADProvider(IAPQ2WebApiHttpClient httpClient, IMemoryCache cache, ADSoap adClient) : base(httpClient, cache)
    {
        ADService = adClient;
    }
}
```