# How to setup the ASNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when running the app in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I know that you can define the **ENVIRONMENT** in asp.net core. Going to `Properties --> Debug --> Environment Variable`.  I've added another environment **DemoLocalEnvironment**. The idea is to run the application in my `local Windows 10 IIS`.

```
"MyApplication": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "DemoLocalEnvironment"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5003"
}
```

After I publish the application to the appropriate folder and setup IIS, none of my conditional code is being executed, the application is even crashing.

How to tell IIS which environment the application is supposed to run under?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432405/11182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor/54432405#54432405) posted by @Lex Li, I found many solution. The one that worked for me is adding this piece of code in the `.csproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentName>DemoLocalEnvironment</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```