# Can't call controller method on dotnet core api: no middleware to handle the request

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm facing an issue with my dotnet core api with angular.
I simply made a login form and a UserController to handle login requests with jwt but whenever i hit the "Login" button and call the UserController's Login method from my angular app with this:

```
this.http.post<any>(environment.baseUrl + `api/user/login`, user)
```

I always get the following message:

"The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request."

I'm looking for more than a solution on this one because i've been searching to fix it the whole day and i couldn't figure out how i could solve it. I looked at iis logs, eventviewer logs. I tried debugging and did a fair amount of internet research, but I can't find a proper way to actually handle this kind of error

Since the error is raised by the dotnet core framework, i don't really know how to determine if it's my controller that is broken or if i made a mistake while configuring services.

How do you usually figure this out?
Thanks for your time and your help in advance ;)

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"); 
        services.AddDbContext<TheCompanyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = $"ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.ConfigureCORS();

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["AppSettings:AuthenticationSecret"]);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

UserController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public UserController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login([FromBody]User user)
    {
        // do login stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted a project from scratch and managed to solve the issue.
I don't really don't know what solved the issue but here's the 3 main thing i did:

- Rework CORS policy
- Rework environment settings for both angular and dotnet
- Solved a database connection issue

My guess is that my environment settings where kind of badly made and i was requesting the wrong api url and CORS blocked me. All of which was hiding my database issue.

Sorry i don't have a proper fix for this, but since i wasted so much time on this, restarting was easier ^^

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was "AllowedHosts": "*" in appsettings.development.json!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setting [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor)  `ASPNETCORE_Environment=Development`.

And you can also try to change "`ouputPath`" in angular.json . Normally it seems to be "`dist/{ProjectName}`". Change this to just "`dist`".

More details, you can refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1514).

Comment: I already changed the outpath for my angular app to be served from the root folder. And adding the Development environment just shows me the exception page when i call the api from postman. I think i'll try to create a new project from scratch, to see if i can spot what i did wrong