# Why does the .Net Core 3.1 project not work when published to the personal hosting server(Not IIS and Azure)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, publish, asp.net-core-3.1

I developed a CMS project on the .Net Core framework and I want to publish it to my own server, but somehow I can't do this.

I will try to explain the process step by step. I go to the project details:

Firstly, I published project on folder then upload to my website with FileZilla.

*My Publish Profile:*

[image]

In this place, I tried to runtime:x64 and deployment: framework-dependent, but I did not get any results from any of them. I can display this way with the configuring in the image.

[image]
*Request ID: |fb17a78-4b085bb85c5b93d5.*

The reason for choosing the Self-Contained is to upload the appropriate .Net Core Runtime for the project to run on the server to be installed.

To give more details, other code blocks are as follows:

*My .csproj:*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<UserSecretsId>aspnet-***CMS-**-**-**-**-**</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
</ItemGroup
</Project>
```

*Startup.cs:*

```
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

*Program.cs:*

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

*appsettings.json:*

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "data source=.\\;initial catalog=***;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

*launchSettings.json:*

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62525",
      "sslPort": 44323
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "***CMS": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this section, I tried to Development instead of Environment, but not working anyway.

I would like to thank all of you for your answers and solutions.

Comment: Storing the environment in the launchsettings.json file is a Visual Studio thing. Won't work for deployments. You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432405/11965297) for more details

Comment: I researched the solutions in other places before. Today I tried the link you recommended during the day, but I have not reached a conclusion yet. @mj1313

Comment: That error message indicates an unhandled exception from somewhere. Learn how to catch and handle that from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1