# Scoped CSS is not auto-generated in Blazor after changing environment

Tags: blazor

`ASP Core 5.0` and `VS 2019 Preview 16.9` have `CSS scopes` feature similar to popular JS frameworks, like Angular. After creating new project, `Host.html` contains [auto-generated CSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-bundling).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyNameSpace.styles.css" />
```

- When [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46389886/437393) is set to `Development`, everything works fine
- Then, I create `appsettings.Live.json` and set environment to `Live`, CSS is not generated and HTTP request trying to load this CSS shows `404 Not Found`

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume you mean `_Host.cshtml`? I created a Blazor server app for .NET 5 called `Blazor50server`, set up a live environment, changing the `launchSettings.json` to **live** and had the same result. I know it worked in earlier betas of 5.0 so not sure why this is

Comment: Oh, I checked on blazor issues page, but didn't see anything. Have logged this report: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28174

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So it appears that the static web assets [are only generated in `Development` mode](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28174#issuecomment-734239932)

I amended the `CreateHostBuilder` method in `Program.cs` accordingly:

```
webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets().UseStartup<Startup>();
```

This appears to fix it.

The environments Production and Staging don't seem to need this when the app is published

Comment: It is documented but it's easy to miss: https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @Quango's answer for `.NET 6`.

Add this line to `Program.cs` before you build the app:

```
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
// Add this: ☝
var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in NET 8 blazor as well and this does work. I am wondering though if your code should be wrapped in the IsDevelopment() if statement? If not would it cause problems when you go to production and such?