# Why do I still get this message even when I swapped to the development environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I changed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to development but I still get this message:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.

Request ID: |1074d166-41e866f34ec46ec9.
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
```

Can you give a solution I'm so disturbed

Comment: There's a bunch of different ways to do this, but different for different versions of asp, asp.net, asp.net-core... I think -core is it's own environment so it's confusing... but see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686302/cant-access-errors-after-publishing-net-core-project#comment121387683_68686302  (Which links to this thread with many different answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor )

Comment: ARE YOU USING iis express or kestrel?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by changing that variable? Are changing this variable when running a published (production) application?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 i'm using IISexpress

Comment: @OH.IO.DEV i'm truying this to display more information about the error that occured.

Comment: include code you've tried.

Comment: Can you create a sample to reproduce the problem? Or you can share the application via OneDrive or Github, it is easier for us to reproduce the problem and help you fix it.