# How to catch exception for a serverless SQL Server cold boot

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application that is hosted in Azure App Service is using a serverless version of SQL Server as a database. It is speaking to SQL Server through Entity Framework Core. I am suspecting this error is occurring because the database is taking time to boot up. It disappears after requesting the page a second or third time.

Is there a way to catch this exception in ASP.NET Core and return a more helpful message to the user based on this specific exception?

**Screen capture of error:**

[image]

Comment: What is the underlying exception? This error is a generic catch-all.

Comment: If your question is only for catching exception message and details in the web app deployed in azure, I think you can enable azure application insights in azure portail->your web app->app insights->choose enable.

Comment: Use a retry strategy

Answer (score 0):

The error you have shared is coming from in-built generic catch. ASP.NET use `UseExceptionHandler` for exception handling that allows us to configure custom error handling route. Please check [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-exception-handling).

This is useful when an application runs under production environment. As you are using Development environment, you should set environment variable `ASPTNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`. To do so, please visit [How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to be considered for publishing an ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor)

To know more about the exception handling in ASP.NET Core 3.1, please visit [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1).