# Dotnet Cli - Publish command not changing Environment Variable in web config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have two asp.net core project which is targeting net5.0. I have web.config in the project as well namely

```
web.config
web.staging.config
web.production.config
```

I try to publish the project using the following command

> **dotnet publish --configuration Staging -o D:\Websites\testwebsite**

The above command works perfectly and the environment variable is set in web.config properly.

> **But when I run the same command in another project it does not change the environment in web.config**

Answer (score 2):

Changes made to the web.config directly are lost, when you run publish again.

There are three ways, you can solve this problem.

**Modifying the project file (.CsProj) file**

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != '' AND '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug' ">
    <EnvironmentName>CustomEnvrionment</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Adding the EnvironmentName Property in the publish profiles**

You will find the publish profile in the folder

Properties/PublishProfiles/<profilename.pubxml>.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Command line options using dotnet publish**

Pass the property EnvironmentName as a command-line option to the dotnet publish command.

```
dotnet publish -c Debug -r win-x64 /p:EnvironmentName=Development
```

All the three methods will update the web.config, when you publish the application.

[How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to be considered for publishing an ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor)

Comment: OK i understand. But why the command is properly working in one project while in other it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling I have found a solution.

My main web.config file was missing a location tag while staging and production files have location tags to be replaced. So that's why when I run the following command transformation was not working properly.

```
dotnet publish --configuration Staging -o D:\Websites\testwebsite
```

So after removing the location tag form staging and production config transformation was done properly.

Here is an example

**web.config**

[image]

**Staging.Config**

[image]

So in short. This command works properly or transforming the config files

**`dotnet publish --configuration Staging -o D:\Websites\testwebsite`**