# How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is how I set `EnvironmentName` variable when publishing my application:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 /p:EnvironmentName=MyCustomValue
```

I got that from this link:

[How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to be considered for publishing an ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor)

As a result my application will try to find settings values from:

`appsettings.MyCustomValue.json` file and if that file does not exist it will attempt to get it from `appsettings.json`.

**Anyways I will like to change the value of `EnvironmentName` variable at runtime. The reason is because I only want to publish my application once and distribute it to multiple servers. It makes no sense to have to publish the same application multiple time each with a different `EnvironmentName` variable.**

This is what I have tried doing

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.WebHost.UseEnvironment(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(/path/to/some/file...));
```

But that does not work.

Comment: The whole idea of an environment variable is that it's set by/on the environment the application is running on, i.e. on the specific server. You should be setting it in the runtime: that's actually an anti-pattern, or at least a code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure your hosting environment (Azure/AWS/Container orchestrator/whatever) to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=YourCustomValue` environment variable for the app. Each environment should provide different values. For instance, in AWS ECS you would do:

```yaml
{
    "family": "",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "image": "app:latest",
            ...
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
                    "value": "YourCustomValue"
                }
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

In docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: app:latest
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'YourCustomValue'
```

If you start it from a shell script:
`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=YourCustomValue dotnet App.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not knew I could add a Configuration to an existing configuration. This is what I ended up doing to override the default `appsettings.MyApp.json` configuration file

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"appsettings.{MyApp.InstanceId}.json");
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    var newConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(filePath, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);  
    builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(newConfigBuilder.Build());
}
```

Now if that file exists my app will first try to read values from that file and if it does not exist it will then failover to `appsettings.MyApp.json` and if that file does not exist then it will failover to `appsettings.json`