# Set Development Enviroment for a specific .NET Core Web Application

Tags: .net-core, iis, web-applications

I've a .Net Core 3.1 web application published on IIS.
I want to force enviroment type to development in order to run api that are not allowed in production.

I run the command :

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

and then I run:

```
iisreset
```

as specified in this article [How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to be considered for publishing an ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor) but the enviroment type seems to always remain production.

I try to run the API via a ngrok tunnel.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.
Simone

Comment: Are you using IIS? Do you have a web.config file in the root of your site? There's ways to control the environment using the web.config, specifically [mentioned on the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551429/1139830).

Comment: @mason I'm using IIS and I've appsettings.json

Comment: Okay, but if you're using IIS, that means you've got a web.config file. Look at the root of your site, then follow the directions in the answer I linked you to, specifically see "Option 2" of their answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set ASPNETCORE\_ENVIRONMENT to be considered for publishing an ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `/M` flag to setx command:

`setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development /M`

The `/M` switch sets the environment variable at the system level. If the `/M` switch isn't used, the environment variable is set for the user account.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows---set-environment-variable-globally)