# How are Azure Dev Ops variables related to dotnet publish (or msbuild)?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

Our .net core web project contained no web.config.  We are aware of that [dotnet publish will create the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0) if it does not exist.

However, we found it odd that the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable was also being set in this new web.config, even when we were NOT [specifying it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432405/852208) with the p:EnvironmentName parameter in the publish option of the dotnet/DotNetCoreCLI@2 command.

[image]

We discovered that we had a variable group in ADO with an EnvironmentName variable defined and publish was implicitly using this variable.

[image]

It is not clear to me how this variable is being transfered to the publish command.  I did find that ADO variables are loaded as environment variables.  But does publish look for environment variables that match environment vars to use as defaults?  In a "[Transform web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-7.0)" documentation there are these somewhat obscure references:

[image]

It references a build "property" but demonstrates a variable syntax.

**How is this EnvironmentName parameter being inferred from this ADO variable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in Azure DevOps pipelines, both predefined system variables and custom user variables, are set as [environment variables](https:///Users/jrdodds/Library/Messages/Attachments/00/00/599E91A1-E5B2-4D97-92D3-10FE0C70D158/image000000.jpg). Tasks (e.g. `DotNetCoreCLI`, `MSBuild`, `PowerShell`) are run with this environment.

The `dotnet publish` command [uses `msbuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild) to perform the publish.

MSBuild maps all environment variables to MSBuild properties. (See "[Use environment variables in a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022)" in the MSBuild docs.)

So to summarize:

- The Azure DevOps variable group defines a variable named `EnvironmentName`.
- The variable group is added to the pipeline creating a pipeline variable named `EnvironmentName`.
- The pipeline variable is set as an environment variable.
- The environment variable is set as an MSBuild property.
- The web.config transform logic looks for and uses the property named `EnvironmentName`

Variable groups can easily be used to set and control MSBuild without explicitly setting properties on the command line. Which is nice unless there is an unintentional name collision.

As a practice you may want to adopt a prefix for naming user variables that are not overrides, to lessen the chances of a name collision.

A note on syntax: In MSBuild a property reference is `$(EnvironmentName)` and in pipeline definitions (YAML and otherwise) a variable substitution is also `$(EnvironmentName)`. The documentation for the web.config transform is talking about an MSBuild property and not a pipeline variable substitution.

Comment: thank you for the answer and you are confirming what we believed.  Is there documentation that indicates msbuild uses env variables as parameters of the same name?

Comment: Yes. See "[Use environment variables in a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022)" from the MSBuild docs. I added that reference to the answer.