# Getting environment variable Development in published web.config

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I publish my ASP.NET Core application, in the `web.config`, I have these entries:

```
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" 
                         value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

I deleted all the environment variables config from my `launchSettings.json`, but it didn't help. I can't understand where is this variable coming from?

My `Properties/PublishProfiles/FolderProfile.xml`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>E:\pub\demo1</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You should specify the command you're running to publish

Comment: @possum I use VS2022, from the menu Build -> Pusblish "WebUI", after FolderProfile and click "Publish" button

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546943/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-be-considered-for-publishing-an-asp-net-cor

Comment: @possum, no, I'm not using the command line to publish, and I don't have `EnvironmentName` property defined in my csproj or publishprofiles xml file (as you can see above)

Comment: @possum solved, I found it in my solution's `web.config`, altough I never added it there myself.